# domcrawler loop and if statement to check if class exists

Tags: api, symfony, loops, if-statement, domcrawler

Hi I'm running into a little problem with DomCrawler. I'm scraping a page and it has a `div` with a class of `.icon3d`. I want to go through the page and for every div with that class I will add an `"3D"` item to an array, and every div without it I will add a `"2D"` item. Here is the code I have so far.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $divs =  $crawler->filter('div.icon3d');
        if(count($divs)){
            $type[] = '3D';
        }else{
            $type[] = '2D';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you're running into?

Comment: currently when I return the `$type` array it returns full of `"3D"` while in reality there only about 4 of them on that page. (only about 4 divs with the .icon3d class). what I want is an array that has the `"3D"` and `"2D"` values in them in the same order as they appear on the page.

Comment: Have you tried with if($crawler->filter('.icon3d')->count()) {} else {}

Comment: @sAcH yea, no success. that always avaluates to true because `$crawler->filter('.icon3d')` is 4

Answer (score 4):

Check [The DomCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) documentation first. `filter` method returns filtered list of nodes, so by calling `->filter('div.icon3d')` returned value will be list of all `div` elements which have `icon3d` class.

First you need to find all `div` elements, loop through them and add either `3D` or `2D` the to array depending on `icon3d` css class existance.

```
$divs = $crawler->filter('div');
foreach ($divs as $node) {
    $type[] = (false !== strpos($node->getAttribute('class'), 'icon3d')) ? '3D' : '2D';
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$crawler->filter('a')->each(function(Crawler $a) {
    $div = $a->filter('div');
    // Div exists
    if ($div->count()) {

    }
});
```

To get crawler node class use

```
$div->getNode(0)->getAttribute('class')
```

Comment: This gets me extremely close, only problem is the div's are in a `<a>` tag, and not all the `<a>` tags have the divs with the `icon3d` class. How can I filter on all the `<a>` tags and then check if they have a div with the `icon3d` class?

Comment: I currently have this: `$divs = $crawler->filter('#schedule li a')->children()->last()->each(function ($node){//run attribute check and return either '3D' or '2D' });` I'm stuck because it checks the last element in the `<a>` and return only 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's the code I used. I'm sure there is a cleaner way.

```
$divs = $crawler->filter('#schedule li a')->each(function($node){
    if ($node->children()->last()->attr('class') == 'icon3d') {
        return '3D';
    }else{
        return '2D';
    }
});
```

Comment: This only matches, if the node has the correct matching class. If you element has more than one class, this will not work!

Comment: you can improve this answer by doing this instead `$classes = preg_split('/\s+/', ($innerNode->attr('class') ?? "")); in_array("searching_class", $classes);`